# center text in an absolute positioned div

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I have the following

```
 <div class="label" 
    style="position: absolute; top: 20px; left: 20px; width: 200px; height: 40px;">
    Label Text
 </div>

 <div class="label" 
    style="position: absolute; top: 70px; left: 20px; width: 200px; height: 120px;">
    Also several lines of 
    Label Text
    may be included
 </div>
```

How can I vertically align the (possibly several lines of) text inside a div.label?

I can add innerHTML if necessary but I can't change the container (class="label").

http://jsfiddle.net/austinfrance/CDTk2/ (now working example)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use something along the lines of

```
 <div class="label" 
style="position: absolute; top: 70px; left: 20px; width: 200px; height: 120px; display: table; vertical-align: middle; border:1px solid #000">
    <span style="display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">
Also several lines of
Label Text
may be included
    </span>
```

please see http://jsfiddle.net/99F6D/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 <div class="label" 
 style="position: absolute; top: 20px; left: 20px; width: 200px; height: 40px;">
    <span style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle"> Label Text </span>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

it's old question but the solution is super easy, because you now about height of div just put line-height with same value of height on css style.

whit your example it must be `line-height:40px`.

good like