# How to center a div which position is absolute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got the following code:

HTML:

```
<div class="label">Middle</div>
<div id='sliderdiv'>
    <input type="range" value="50" min="0" max="100" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 .label {
     position: absolute;
     margin-top: 13px;
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     z-index: 3;
 }
 input.ui-slider-input {
     display: none !important;
 }
 #sliderdiv .ui-slider-track {
     margin-left: 15px;
 }
```

But I can't center my text div, is there a solution for this problem or is it not possible with css?

I could calculate it dynamically with javascript for sure, but I'd like to avoid that.

Here is the live code for you: http://jsfiddle.net/VmwQM/

Edit:

This is not what I want:

```
.label {
         position: absolute;
         margin-top: 13px;
         margin-left: 50%;
         z-index: 3;
     }
```

Because I want my text middle at 50% and not my text to start at 50%.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I horizontally center an absolute positioned element inside a 100% width div?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16758102/how-do-i-horizontally-center-an-absolute-positioned-element-inside-a-100-width)

Comment: Not really, because my text size varies. I've got more then one text div. This solution would let start my text at 50% but I want the middle of my text at 50%.

Comment: @Thunder: which div you want to be centered.

Comment: In that case, possible duplicate of [Center text in an absolute position div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11690828/center-text-in-an-absolute-positioned-div)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

**[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/VmwQM/3/)**

```
.label {
 position:absolute;
 top:11px;
 width:100%;
 z-index: 3;
 text-align:center;
}
input.ui-slider-input {
 display: none !important;
}
#sliderdiv .ui-slider-track {
 margin-left: 15px;
}
```

Good Luck..

Comment: Sorry, but I need the text inside the slider.

Comment: @PradeepPansari can you explain what you've done here? That way other people can take this answer and apply it to slightly different but similar problems.

Answer (score 4):

Do you want something like this:

```
 body {
     text-align: center;
 }
 .label {
   width: 100%;
 }
```

And your text will be inside the slider:

<kbd>**[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/VmwQM/2/)**</kbd>

Comment: +1, nice and simple. To OP: Just make sure you might wrap the HTML inside a separate "container" to centre the text in so your whole site doesn't get it's text now centred.

Comment: Thanks! Another option would be to add `text-align: center` to the `label`, because in this case he's got `width: 100%`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot center elements using margin:auto that are absolutely positioned. The display-attribute of them is automatically set to *inline*.

[Why margin:auto doesn't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14756204/why-marginauto-doesnt-work)

jQuery-Solution can be:

```
var left = $(window).width() / 2 - $('.label').width() / 2;
$('.label').css('left',left+'px');
```

Answer (score 0):

The `margin: 0 auto` won't work for absolutely positioned element. Just set the `left` or `right` property to 50%:

```
.label {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 13px;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 3;
}
```

And don't forget that absolute positioning is calculated with respect to the parent. You may have other markup around beyond that example that would affect what `position: absolute` does when applied to `.label`

Comment: Disregard this, Pradeep's answer is more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -25px;
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VmwQM/5/)**

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div class="slide-holder">
    <div id='sliderdiv'>
        <input type="range" value="50" min="0" max="100" />
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.slide-holder {
    text-align: center;
}
#sliderdiv {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can center it provided you give a width value:

```
.label {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 13px auto auto;
    width: 3rem;
    right: 0; left: 0;
}
```

More info on centering absolute elements with just css [in this smashing magazine article](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/09/absolute-horizontal-vertical-centering-css/)