# Centering text on absolutely positioned parent div's top-left corner using only CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to center text, both vertically and horizontally, on the pixel that would normally be the top-left of an absolutely positioned div. Here is the html:

```
<div style="position:absolute; background-color:#EEEEEE; left:100px; top:100px;">
    <div style="position:relative; top:-50%; left:-50%;">
        My Centered Text
    </div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fHJkE/1/

As you cans see the html centers the text horizontally, but not vertically. The 'top:-50%' styling doesn't seem to have any affect.

Why is the percentage based top being ignored while left isn't? What can I do to have it center vertically?

EDIT:

Since my question is being misinterpreted, this is what I want:

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [center text in an absolute positioned div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11690828/center-text-in-an-absolute-positioned-div)

Comment: I'm trying to center on the top-left corner of the div, not inside the div.

Comment: All you need to do is set a height on the container div and you will get your desired effect.

Comment: Is there anyway to have the height calculated from the height of the text?

Comment: You can set the height of the container to `1em`, that way the height will vary depending on the font-size that is set in the `body` CSS.

Comment: The height of the text may differ from that of the body CSS :(

Comment: Try position:relative for the text element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Top is not being ignored. Top property, when percentage, is relative to the height of a parent object. Since your parent doesn't have a height, `top` won't work. Unless, of course you set the top in pixels.

Comment: Why does the left property work when the width isn't explicitly defined?

Comment: It isn't being "explicitly" defined, but it IS being defined by the content within the div, so therefore it has a width to work from.

Comment: Because a div is `display:block` by default. This property establishes a width value as full, but doesn't set a height value.

Comment: Is there anything to establish both height and width as full?

Answer (score 0):

try this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ic0o09988/fHJkE/4/)
i removed ur div and replaced it with `<p>` **line-height:(parent element's height)px;**
will center your text at the middle;(vertically)

Comment: I need the text centered on the top-left corner of the div, not in the center.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do it this way, the only way to get the computed height without setting it, is through Javascript. Try it, it will do the trick:

```
var dv = document.getElementById("dv-align");
dv.style.top = "-" + (dv.offsetHeight/2) + "px";
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fHJkE/5/