# Vertically center text inside an absolutely-positioned div

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to vertically center text inside a div that is positioned absolutely.

I have tried `table-cell` approach with no luck. This is a responsive layout, so I'm trying to avoid setting fixed heights and prefer not to use Javascript either.

Thanks

[Link to jsbin demo](http://jsbin.com/mucoyali/1/edit)

HTML & CSS:

```
<div class="page-banner" style="background: url(http://www.bimga.com.php53-3.ord1-1.websitetestlink.com//wp-content/uploads/BIMGA_Website_InteriorPage_Banners_About.jpg) no-repeat scroll 0 0 / cover transparent">
    <img style="visibility:hidden" src="http://www.bimga.com.php53-3.ord1-1.websitetestlink.com//wp-content/uploads/BIMGA_Website_InteriorPage_Banners_About.jpg">
    <div class="left">
        <div class="page-banner-text">this text needs to be verticall centered</div>
    </div>
</div>

<style type="text/css">
.page-banner {
    margin-bottom: 35px;
    list-style: none;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 0;
    position: relative;
}

.page-banner img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.page-banner .left {
    background-color: rgba(10, 65, 142, .75);
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    width: 50%;
}    
</style>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [center text in an absolute positioned div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11690828/center-text-in-an-absolute-positioned-div)

Comment: Not sure it is a duplicate. Here, the height is 100% and that's why it's not working with vertical-align:middle;

Comment: @Paulie_D I have mentioned in my description that the `table-cell` approach did not work for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could use a `transform` like so:

[Have a jsBin!](http://jsbin.com/mucoyali/4/edit)

CSS

```
.page-banner-text {
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    position: absolute;
}
```

[More information](http://davidwalsh.name/css-vertical-center) on this technique.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is, set the text position to absolute.
Then give it a top: 50%; and give it a top margin of minus half its height.

Comment: I don't know the height though (unless I calculate it in Javascript which I'm trying to avoid). This is a responsive layout.

Comment: You should know the height of the text even in a responsive layout. If not, set up a javascript to edit the top margin on resize based on half the text height.

Answer (score 0):

I would not prefer using position absolute and top: 50% for better multi browser support (espesially on older IE versions) so I would prefer adding line-height: x em; in your .page banner class. Em because you have defined the height by % so it needs to always be on the center no matter the actual pixel height.

```
.page-banner .left:after {

content: "Background text";
position: absolute;
top: 40%;
left: 35%;
z-index: -1;

}
```

Comment: Try resizing the window though. I can't give it a "fixed" height or line-height.

Comment: I believe in that case you need to use javaScript or jQuery

Comment: Sorry I forgot totally about css pseudo commands. See my updated answer :)